# Setting the current light in recent version of Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

I have a not so old Asymptote code and my settings of `currentlight` do not longer work with a more recent version. This is the code:

```
currentlight = light(gray(0.85), ambient=black, specularfactor=3,
                     (0.5,0.5,1), specular=gray(0.6), viewport=false);
currentlight.background = rgb("363940ff");
```

The compilation complains about the usage of the `light` function. Something has changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four years ago Asymptote upgraded from the Phong-Blinn lighting model to physically based rendering, which has no `ambient` attribute. The `viewport` argument was removed a few months before that. Just use

```
currentlight = light(gray(0.85), specularfactor=3,(0.5,0.5,1), specular=gray(0.6));
```

`currentlight` also accepts an optional `background` argument.